# Could not install gems on recently created EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, amazon-ec2

I created a EC2 instance from a BitNami stack, with ruby, rails, etc all configured.
I created a new app in /home/bitnami/htdocs 
Apache is pointing there

However bundle install fails:

```
    /bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/sqlite3': Permission denied
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.sqlite3.time] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/bitnami/.bundler/tmp/3003/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bitnami/.bundler/tmp/3003/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The problem is that it clear needs sudo access to install sqlite. If I do `sudo bundle install`  I am pretty sure that I will have problems in the future.

Actually, sudo gem install sqlite fails because it can't find sqlite.h.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install dependencies.  Here are the ones for ruby

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
```

You may be able to just install sqlite3 but doing all of these should give you smooth sailing.

Here is the most succinct article i've found on it.
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04